# How does C compiler declare array when there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

This may be a simple question but I am trying to understand how the compiler assigns all the elements in the array to zero for example:
''' array[5] = {0}; '''

I checked gcc.gnu.org for some explanation but was unsuccessful. Maybe I am looking in the wrong location. I also checked C99 and stumbled upon section 6.7.8/21, but it does not tell me how it is initialized. I also looked at other posts about this topic but most address what happens, not how it happens.

Anyway, my questions are:

How does the compiler assign all the elements to zero through this single expression?

Where can I find information on how the compiler works, specifically with the example above?

Thanks...

Comment: With my experience in assembly, 'array[5]={0}' will be converted into a loop functionality in assembly.

Comment: You could see it for yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/9z4K1x

Comment: @ChungHuang It sounds very fishy. Which compiler produces a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 6.7.9 19 says:

> … all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

C 2018 6.7.9 10 says, for objects with static storage duration that are not initialized explicitly:

> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

Thus, when you initialize part but not all of an array, the rules of the C standard require the compiler to initialize the other elements to zero for arithmetic types and a null pointer for pointer types.

Compilers are free to implement this as they choose. The method is not usually document, and it varies by situation: For a small array, the compiler might generate explicit instructions. For a large array, the compiler might generate a loop (including a single instruction that implements a loop to zero memory) or call a library routine. Or, if the compiler can detect that initialization is not actually necessary for correct program operation, it might omit it. For example, if the compiler can see that a subsequent assignment sets an array element to a value before that array element is used, the compiler might omit any zeroing of the array element and instead let the assignment be the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation detail that will vary widely between different compilers and different source code, but the general answer is the same - the compiler will generate whatever code is necessary to zero out the uninitialized elements.

Here's how things shake out on my implementation (gcc version 7.3.1).

Source code (file `init.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int arr[5] = {0};

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    printf( "arr[%zu] = %d\n", i, arr[i] );

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled using the command

```
gcc -o init -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror init.c
```

gives me the following machine code (viewed using `objdump -d init`):

```
00000000004004c7 <main>:
  4004c7:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004c8:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004cb:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp        ;; allocates space for arr and i, rounded up to multiple of 4   
  4004cf:   48 c7 45 e0 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)  ;; zeros out a[0] and a[1]
  4004d6:   00 
  4004d7:   48 c7 45 e8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)  ;; zeros out a[2] and a[3]
  4004de:   00 
  4004df:   c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)  ;; zeros out a[4]
  4004e6:   48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)   ;; zeros out i
...
```

Above a certain size, explicitly zeroing out one or two elements at a time gets cumbersome - when I change the array size to 50, the generated assembly code became

```
00000000004004c7 <main>:
  4004c7:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004c8:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4004cb:   48 81 ec d0 00 00 00    sub    $0xd0,%rsp
  4004d2:   48 8d 95 30 ff ff ff    lea    -0xd0(%rbp),%rdx
  4004d9:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4004de:   b9 19 00 00 00          mov    $0x19,%ecx
  4004e3:   48 89 d7                mov    %rdx,%rdi
  4004e6:   f3 48 ab                rep stos %rax,%es:(%rdi)
  4004e9:   48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
  4004f0:   00 
  ...
```

The `rep stos` instruction is essentially a loop (I don't speak x86 assembly fluently, somebody else will have to explain exactly how it works).  It zeros out each element of the array in succession, rather than zeroing out the entire array in a single instruction if I understand it correctly.